# Background images Wordpress SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo

Hi I have several doubts about Wordpress SEO that I don't find answer.

1- I have several a href with background images, I tried to envolve this with a img tag adding the attribute alt but it's shown in each image, How could i hidden it? or what could i do for apply SEO to a background-image adding alt?

```
<img alt="This is a test" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink()
) ?>">      
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ) ?>" class="overlay"></a>         
</img>
```

2- If i add a keyword on an image, This image keyword compute in the 2%-3% max of keyword in the page?

3- If I add an alt to an image, this alt text would be shown when I search it in Google??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that is invalid HTML. The following is correct:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ) ?>" class="overlay">
<img alt="This is a test" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink()
) ?>" /></a>
```

You can link an Image, but you can not place a link inside a image in this way.

This is not a WordPress question but more a general question on SEO. Background images will not affect your SEO (except maybe in terms of bad page load times). They are intended to be background images and therefore do not have a semantic meaning.

Adding alt text to an image is a good idea especially if the image contains text or has a meaning. Using images with correctly specified alt texts can be good for SEO (at least a little bit).

Comment: Yes, but if I add a img tag into a href like you said I can add the alt attribute with the text for the SEO and the src attribute empty so I have SEO for background images, anyway I am not sure if this is "legal" for google so I am asking. I don't want show an image with the tag img I want just to use the alt of this. I want to do this because my website just has photos, about 300 post just with images and I need some SEO.

Comment: If an image has more than aesthetic value (that means content value) it just should NOT be a background image. Therefore I do not think that search engines will tolerate such a hack.

Comment: You could try using a title or longdesc attribute on the container element however this will not be directly associated with the image then.

Comment: It's the theme I buyed so I cannot do nothing, if I use a title or longdesc attribute. Is it the same as alt img? (talking about SEO) and other ask, Do you know if I use some keywords in this attributes, compute about the 2-3% max about keywords and I can write and repeat the keywords like I want?

Comment: It is not the same like an alt attribute but I guess search engines will at least use them and also repeating of the keywords is probably a good idea (but not sure about that). A clean workaround is to create a child theme which uses images instead of backgrounds but this requires some work ofc